# Sort a list of pairs of integers java

Tags: java, integer, compare, comparator

I want to sort an arraylist of pairs of integers.  So far I've been able to sort them according to the first element, but I get something like (1,2), (1,-2).  I want to also sort them according to the second element so I can get a correct sorted arraylist, but I cant seem to make it work.

The code for the first element sorting is:

```
private class FirstElmComparator implements Comparator<Pair> {

    public int compare(Pair pr1, Pair pr2) {
        return pr1.compareFirstElms(pr2);
    }
}
```

and compareFirstElms function is the following:

```
protected int compareFirstElms (Pair p) {
    return (new Integer (this.p1)).compareTo(new Integer (p.p1));
}
```

I can think of making the second element comparator as the following:

```
private class SecondElmComparator implements Comparator<Pair> {

    public int compare(Pair pr1, Pair pr2) {
        return pr1.compareSecondElms(pr2);
    }
}

protected int compareSecondElms (Pair p) {
    return (new Integer (this.p2)).compareTo(new Integer (p.p2));
}
```

NOTE: p1 and p2 are the first and second element in a pair.

But I think it will override the first element sorting order, or am I mistaken?
Can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create one common comparator that evaluates both elements of the Pair.

```
public int compare(Pair pr1, Pair pr2) {
    int firstResult = pr1.compareFirstElms(pr2);
    if (firstResult == 0) { //First comparison returned that both elements are equal
        return pr1.compareSecondElms(pr2);
    } else {
        return firstResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple, implement it like this:

- If the first elements of the pairs to compare are different, then sort on the first element.
- Otherwise (if the first elements are equal), sort on the second element.

Comment: and i implement this in the second element compareTo method?

Comment: No, in your `compare` method just call `compareFirstElms`, if it indicates that the first elements are different then return the result of that call, and if they are the same then call `compareSecondElms` and return the result of that.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't use two distinct comparators but one (which might in turn call others to do the internal work).

So in pseudocode, the comparison would look like this:

```
public int compare(Pair pr1, Pair pr2) {

  int result = compare(p1.first, p2.first);

  if( result == 0 ) {
    result = compare(p1.second, p2.second);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first off, you need to write an explicit method for that:

```
public int compare(Pair p) {
    int first = compareFirstElms(p);
    return first == 0 ? compareSecondElms(p) : first;
}
```

Secondly, don’t over-engineer. Comparing two ints is as simple as writing `this.p1 - p.p1`. No need for conversions.

Thirdly, I would choose explicit, concise yet *complete* names. Don’t arbitrarily abbreviate parts of words, this doesn’t exactly help readability. How about `compareByFirst` and `compareBySecond`, respectively?

Comment: "Comparing two ints is as simple as writing this.p1 - p.p1" ... provided, that all values stay in a safe range. `Integer.MAX_VALUE - Integer.MIN_VALUE == -1`.

Comment: `Integer.MIN_VALUE - X` would be even worse because of the overflow.